# rspec class methods TestFirst Tutorial Tem converter

Tags: ruby

working on a project and lost to begin...Here is the descriptions from spec:

```
describe Temperature do
describe "can be constructed with an options hash" do
describe "in degrees fahrenheit" do
  it "at 50 degrees" do
    Temperature.new(:f => 50).in_fahrenheit.should == 50
  end
```

Stuck on this for awhile, I'm thinking my problem has to do with getting the arguments, but cant figure out how. My code is bringing in the result "nil" instead of 50.

```
 class Temperature
    attr_accessor :f

 def in_fahrenheit
 @f
 end


 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you're not setting a value to accessor `:f` anywhere. You should define your own constructor for this:

```
class Temperature

  def initialize(args)
    self.f = args[:f]
  end

  attr_accessor :f
  def in_fahrenheit
    f
  end
end


t = Temperature.new(:f => 50)

t.f # => 50
t.in_fahrenheit # => 50
```